# getting error in angular eslint when i upgrade angular from 13 to 14

Tags: angular, updates

when i try to upgrade angular from 13 to 14 i am getting this error

> Package "@angular-eslint/schematics" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/cli" (requires ">= 13.0.0 < 14.0.0", would install "14.0.0").
> Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
> Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
> You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.

when i do --force update the code is failing in npm run test

> This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
> but Angular version 14.2.12 was found instead.

how can i upgrade my project to angular 14 ,
this is my package.json before update to 14

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "prod": "ng build --configuration production",
    "test": "ng test --watch=false --code-coverage",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "sonar": "sonar-scanner",
    "install-lib": "npm un case-management && npm i ./libs/case-management-0.0.1.tgz && npm start"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "^0.1303.9",
    "@angular/animations": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/cdk": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/common": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/compiler": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/core": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/forms": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/material": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^14.2.12",
    "@angular/router": "^14.2.12",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.10.0",
    "jasmine-marbles": "^0.8.4",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~7.0.0",
    "karma": "~6.3.16",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-firefox-launcher": "^2.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "npm": "^8.19.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^13.0.0",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.7",
    "@angular-eslint/builder": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/schematics": "13.5.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "13.5.0",
    "@angular/cli": "^13.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^13.3.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.9.1",
    "@types/node": "^16.10.9",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.17.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.17.0",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
    "esbuild": "^0.14.41",
    "eslint": "^8.17.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-header": "^3.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.25.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "39.3.3",
    "eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "1.2.2",
    "eslint-plugin-sonarjs": "^0.14.0",
    "husky": "^4.3.8",
    "lint-staged": "^10.5.4",
    "piscina": "^3.2.0",
    "prettier": "2.2.1",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "sonar-scanner": "^3.1.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  },
  "husky": {
    "hooks": {
      "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
    }
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "**/*.ts": [
      "eslint --fix",
      "prettier --write --ignore-unknown"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share your package.json please?

Comment: yes added it in the question, please see

Comment: IMHO I guess one eslint plugin is not yet compatible with ng14

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Option 1**

Since you already upgraded angular from 13 to 14 by using the `--force` flag:

```
ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14 --force
```

What you want to do next is an angular upgrade of eslint like this:

```
ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@14
```

**Option 2**

If you do not want to use `--force` during your angular upgrade, you can flip  the step order above, removing `--force` and this should work for you:

```
ng update @angular-eslint/schematics@14
```

Then

```
ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14
```

Answer (score 4):

**Another option** is to add `@angular-eslint/schematics` to Angular upgrade command. In my case the problem was during upgrade to Angular 15 so the command I used was:

`ng update @angular/core@15 @angular/cli@15 @angular-eslint/schematics@15`